# Unable to run sql file in Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to write a self-contained integration test for my Spring Boot application.

The Test class is like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Sql("/create_schema.sql")
public class UserControllerTest {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private String baseUrl = "http://localhost";


    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = null;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        baseUrl = baseUrl.concat(":").concat(port+ "").concat("/users");
    }


    @Test
    @Sql("/create.sql")
    public void test1() {
        User user = restTemplate.getForObject(baseUrl.concat("/users/{username}"), User.class, "username1");

        Assertions.assertNotNull(user);
        Assertions.assertEquals(100L, user.getId());
    }
}
```

The create_schema.sql file is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE USERINFO
(
    USER_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
    PWD VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    USERNAME VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
);
```

The create.sql file just insert one line of data:

```
INSERT INTO USERINFO (USER_ID, USERNAME, PWD) VALUES(100, 'username1','$2y$12$iUHx4NGJpgJKskDhhN12y.e/D9tzHe/B7DbDOf37Pfx0xDymIazpi');
```

When I run the test. The error I was given is

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USERINFO" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO USERINFO (USER_ID, USERNAME, PWD) VALUES(100, 'username1','$2y$12$iUHx4NGJpgJKskDhhN12y.e/D9tzHe/B7DbDOf37Pfx0xDymIazpi') [42102-200]
```

This is very strange because the create_schema.sql runs fine and a table USERINFO should be created in H2.

In my IDE (IntelliJ), the

```
USERINFO (USER_ID, USERNAME, PWD)
```

in the INSERT statement is shown as red and the IDE says "Unable to resolve table USERINFO".

What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you show the complete exception with stack trace ?

Answer (score 1):

Use **@SqlMergeMode(MergeMode.MERGE)** at class level to merge the sql queries and run them both.
It seems like your class level SQL annotation is overridden by method level SQL annotation.
Hence the create schema sql is never executed.

For further reading please refer: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/sql-example-spring-test